# Nginx reverse proxy re-direct to Account/Login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The redirection to the standard MVC "Login" page does not work.

I develop under Windows using Visual Studio 2017 - This a a standard templated Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC package.

All works well locally under Windows.

However when I publish to a Ubuntu 16.04-x64 box, the redirection fails.

I have Nginx providing reverse proxy as follows:

`server {
    listen 24147;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}`

And in my Startup.cs:

`public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var forwardedHeadersOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
    {
        ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
        // ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All  (also tried)
    };
    forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();   // Tried both with and
    forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();    // without these lines
    app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeadersOptions);
    // .....
    app.UseAuthentication();
    // .....
}`

Program.cs:

`public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup()
        .UseUrls("http://localhost:5001")
        .Build();
}`

All hyper-links within the web page are correct eg:  `"myserver.com:24147/Home/Online"`, but the redirection when attempting to access a page that requires authorisation gets a "404 Not Found".

Under Ubuntu the redirect address used is `"myserver.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FOnline"`  (Note the missing port number)

Under Windows the address used is `"localhost:5001/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FOnline"` (correct, with port number)

I have scoured Google and StackOverflow for solutions and tried all configurations put forward - all to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a Fiddler trace it similar?

Comment: @Tratcher: Thank you for encouraging me to create a Fiddler trace. It guided me to the solution to the problem outlined below.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not due to the asp.net Core framework at all, but the contents of the Nginx reverse proxy setup.

Nginx was omitting the port number in it's  302 (redirect) "Location" header.

Resolve this issue by changing a line in the reverse proxy configuration file:

From:

`proxy_set_header Host $host;`

To:

`proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;`

All now works as expected.